# How do I put a warning/message on a specific number of a counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, battery, batterylevel, batterymanager

I am using a system in my website that identify the amount of battery the user have in his phone, the system is "battery-api".

I would like to insert a warning when the battery is over 10% (for example) like, "Hey, you need to charge your phone, you can always use our products..."

it's possible?

Comment: Yes, It is possible if user is using latest chrome browser. More https://caniuse.com/#feat=battery-status

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API#Browser_compatibility

Comment: What did you try? What problems were encountered? That API has limited browser support

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the functionality using the [Battery Status API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API). The below code is a slightly modified version of the [Example on this page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API)

```
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

  battery.addEventListener('levelchange', function(){
    updateLevelInfo();
  });

  function updateLevelInfo(){
    var percentage = battery.level * 100;
    if(percentage < 10){ // Show message };
  }

});
```

I recommend checking the browser compatibility however if it's satisfactory.

Comment: I feel dirty knowing that this solution, while valuable information, is going to lead to ads for phone chargers based on battery state given the question.

Comment: Firefox removed support for the API in Firefox 52 due to privacy concerns. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.platform/5U8NHoUY-1k/9ybyzQIYCAAJ